# Vector is out of range

Tags: c++, exception, vector

A good day to all stackers.
I am running my program in Quincy2005 and I have this following error.
"Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range"
"what(): vector::_M_range_check"

The below is my bunch of codes

```
int ptextLoc,ctextLoc;       //location of the plain/cipher txt
char ctextChar;     //cipher text variable
//by default, the location of the plain text is even
bool evenNumberLocBool = true;
ifstream ptextFile;
//open plain text file
ptextFile.open("ptext.txt");

    //character by character encryption
    while (!ptextFile.eof())
    {

        //get (next) character from file and store it in a variable ptextChar
        char ptextChar = ptextFile.get();

        //find the position of the ptextChar in keyvector Vector
        ptextLoc = std::find(keyvector.begin(), keyvector.end(), ptextChar) - keyvector.begin();

        //if the location of the plain text is even
        if (  ((ptextLoc % 2) == 0) || (ptextLoc == 0) )
            evenNumberLocBool = true;
        else
            evenNumberLocBool = false;

        //if the location of the plain text is even/odd, find the location of the cipher text    
        if (evenNumberLocBool)
            ctextLoc = ptextLoc + 1;
        else
            ctextLoc = ptextLoc - 1;


        //store the cipher pair in ctextChar variable
        ctextChar = keyvector.at(ctextLoc);

        cout << ctextChar;

    }
```

Contents of ptext.txt
             ab cd ef

If the first letter is 'a' which is at the position 0, the pair cipher alphabet will be kevector[1].

LATEST UPDATE: I have found the line which has been creating this error.
ctextChar = keyvector.at(ctextLoc);
However, I am not sure why is it happening with this line.
I hope someone will be able to guide me.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector`'s `size()` returns a value `1 --- N`, where as `at()` relies on values `0 --- (N - 1)`. Therefore, you should use:

```
if (keyvector.size() != 0 && ctextLoc > keyvector.size() - 1)
  break;
```

Comment: `push_back()` returns `void`. Also I do not think, that this line is made for storing in the vector but reading the data from the vector, so it should be okay.

Comment: Still one minor flaw: `size()` can return 0 when the vector is empty. One should simply distinguish between the size and the last valid index, where the latter is `size() - 1`, if the vector is not empty.

Comment: @all, I have actually tried debugging and it turns out "ctextChar = keyvector.at(ctextLoc)" is causing the error. but i still am not sure why is it so.

Comment: @Andres Yes, that's where the error occurs, but it's because your logic is faulty and is allowing you to access a part of the vector that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (ctextLoc > keyvector.size())
```

should probably be

```
if (ctextLoc >= keyvector.size())
```